# Are raw eggs dangerous?

Tags: nutrition, diet, food-safety

I have two raw eggs every morning with / for breakfast. I have chickens and only eat raw eggs from our chickens, never store-bought.

I have been told that raw eggs can be dangerous, including the risk of salmonella.

**Are raw eggs dangerous? What are the risks / benefits?**

Comment: The risks include infection with Salmonella and biotin deficiency, among other. Both issues have been discussed on this very site already, I believe.